# A new furniture for an empty room. Is the article correct?

Tags: articles

> **A** new furniture for an empty room.

It's a grammar assignment related to articles. What made me confused here is either 'a' new furniture or 'the' new furniture. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

"Furniture" is a mass noun (per the [Oxford English](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/furniture)), so it can't have an indefinite article in front.

To state this another way, "A new furniture" is wrong because you can't have "one furniture", since "furniture" is a mass noun. You can have "one piece of furniture" and hence "a piece of furniture".

"The new furniture" is grammatically valid. Remember that "furniture" is still a mass noun here; it's not serving to indicate any specific piece of furniture, unless there's other context to restrict it.